# oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible in Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I believe that oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible has been deprecated in Oracle 11

Is this because for a DATE column Oracle is now doing what it did before 8i e.g. return an instance of java.sql.Timestamp  for a DATE column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their FAQ covers it:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#08_00

> Oracle JDBC 11.1 fixes this problem. Beginning with this release the driver maps SQL DATE columns to java.sql.Timestamp by default. There is no need to set V8Compatible to get the correct mapping. V8Compatible  is strongly deprecated. You should not use it at all. If you do set it to true it won't hurt anything, but you should stop using it.

As mentioned above, the 11.1 drivers by default convert SQL DATE to Timestamp  when reading from the database. This always was the right thing to do and the change in 9i was a mistake. The 11.1 drivers have reverted to the correct behavior.